# What's the use of reparametrizing a curve with respect to arc length?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that the magnitude of the derivative is always 1, but why is that important? Are there other reasons too?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Comment: It's just useful. There are lots of important theoretical results - for example, involving the curvature, the torsion, geodesics- which are intrinsic and have nothing to do with the specific parametrization you employ. Choosing the arc-length parameter simply makes the computations easier, keeping the important ideas without any loss of information and without innecesary tedious computations. PS: There are tons of excellent books where you can find these things in great detail. Do you need references?